# Detecting when object is fully in collider

Tags: unity, 2d

How to make that when object is fully in collider, just that moment "something happens", now I only know triggering.Hmm I mean when that cube is fully in the collider. 
 [image]

Comment: @Tyyppi_77
I tried if (other.bounds.Contains(this.bounds))
but it is showing error at (this.bounds) How to resolve that error?

Comment: @Naeem See my edit to the answer, apparently modern game engines do not bother to provide reasonable method overloads for collision checks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OnTriggerStay` callback, and make sure that you don't trigger the action before the collider is fully container by the container. So basically you just need an extra check inside `OnTriggerStay`.

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.bounds.Contains(this.bounds.min) && other.bounds.Contains(this.bounds.max))
    {
        PerformAction();
    }
}
```

Unity doesn't provide a standard functionality for this, but this very basic approach should do the job.

Comment: This one will work great. Another way is with raycast distance without getting into collision stuff.

Comment: bounds.Contains accepts Vector3 as argument, not another bounds

Comment: [You can write an extension method for this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/143503/39518) if it's something you'd like as a single method call.

Comment: That answer is a bit more complicated than you need, this is simpler https://answers.unity.com/questions/292467/check-if-is-encapsulated.html